# Google Analytics custom variables multiple values per slot

Tags: google-analytics

Since I can't set multiple values for the same slot at the same time using code like this

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'XXXXXXXX']);
    _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'mydomain.com']);
    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',1,'ONE',"www.mydomain.com/ONE",1]);
    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',1,'TWO',"www.mydomain.com/ONE",1]);
    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',2,'THREE',"www.mydomain.com/ONE",1]);
    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',2,'FOUR',"www.mydomain.com/ONE",1]);     
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

Is there a different strategy to obtain the same results?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can concatenate multiple values with a delimiting character value1#value2#value3, send them as a single variable and use regular expressions to create segments or filters based on the individual parts.

Be aware though there is a limit on [total number of characters](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables#usage):

> The total combined length of any custom variable name and value may
>   not exceed 128 characters.